# Face Swap Using Face Detection Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, crop, face-detection, ondraw

I am trying to do Face swap kind of application using facedetection. Till now i get the faces detected in bitmap and draw oval on the faces detected. But now i need to use the faces inside the oval so that i can swap two faces. Is it possible. I need some suggestions regarding this.

My activity class as follows

```
public class FaceDetectionActivity extends Activity 
{


public MyView faceview;
public ImageView gallery;
private Uri imageURI;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    faceview = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.faceview);

    gallery=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    gallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0 );

        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode==0){

        imageURI = data.getData(); 


        try {
            Bitmap b = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageURI);

            faceview.myBitmap=b;


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 //              TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
 //              TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        faceview.invalidate(); 

        }


        faceview.invalidate(); 
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
        Log.e("result", "BAD");
    }
}


}
```

and my view class

```
public class MyView extends ImageViewTouchBase {

public RectF rectF;
public Bitmap myBitmap;
private int width, height;
private FaceDetector.Face[] detectedFaces;
private int NUMBER_OF_FACES=10;
private FaceDetector faceDetector;
private int NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED;
private float eyeDistance;
Matrix mImageMatrix;

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFatoryOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapFatoryOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.familyportrait,bitmapFatoryOptions);
    width=myBitmap.getWidth();
    height=myBitmap.getHeight();
    detectedFaces=new FaceDetector.Face[NUMBER_OF_FACES];
    faceDetector=new FaceDetector(width,height,NUMBER_OF_FACES);
    NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED=faceDetector.findFaces(myBitmap, detectedFaces);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    if(myBitmap!=null)
    {


    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0,0, null);

    }
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    for(int count=0;count<NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED;count++)
    {
        Face face=detectedFaces[count];
        PointF midPoint=new PointF();
        face.getMidPoint(midPoint);

        eyeDistance=face.eyesDistance();

    float   left = midPoint.x - (float)(1.4 * eyeDistance);
    float   right = midPoint.x + (float)(1.4 * eyeDistance);
    float    top = midPoint.y - (float)(1.8 * eyeDistance);
    float    bottom = midPoint.y + (float)(1.8 * eyeDistance);

    Rect imageRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
     rectF = new RectF();

    rectF.set(left,top,right,bottom);

    canvas.drawOval(rectF, myPaint);


    }
}

}
```

Now i want the content inside the oval to be selected. Please suggest me some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out. I am creating another bitmap with the variables Left,Right,Top and Bottom from the above code. and then i get a square bitmap of the faces.I am extracting circular bitmap from the square bitmap faces. Thats it.

Comment: its a bit cumbersome code. I will write a tutorial and share it in a week.

Comment: Hey @Sandeep, I love your idea, would love to see the code if it's possible.

Comment: Hi can you explain what you mean by providing some code?

Comment: @SandeepR Could you please share your implementation ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ProgressA {

    public static final String FACE_1 = "face_1";
    public static final String FACE_2 = "face_2";

    private ImageView mIvForDetect;
    private ImageView mIvForDetect2;
    private ImageView mIvForDetect3;
    private ImageView mIvForDetect4;
    //private Bitmap baseBTM;
    private Bitmap face1BTM;
    private Bitmap face2BTM;

    boolean face1Done = false;
    boolean face2Done = false;

    private FirebaseVisionFaceDetector detector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mIvForDetect = findViewById(R.id.iv_main_for_detect);
        mIvForDetect2 = findViewById(R.id.iv_main_for_detect2);
        mIvForDetect3 = findViewById(R.id.iv_main_for_detect3);
        mIvForDetect4 = findViewById(R.id.iv_main_for_detect4);
        //baseBTM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.paj);
        mIvForDetect.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.jolie));
        mIvForDetect2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pitt));

        detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(buildCloudVisionOptions());

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showProgressDialog();
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        detectFace(mIvForDetect, FACE_1, null);
                        detectFace(mIvForDetect2,FACE_2, null);
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkFaces() {
        if (face1Done && face2Done){
            swapFaces();
        }
    }

    private void swapFaces() {
        detectFace(mIvForDetect, FACE_1, face2BTM);
        detectFace(mIvForDetect2, FACE_2, face1BTM);
    }

    private void detectFace(final ImageView view, final String face, final Bitmap fakeFace) {

        final Bitmap baseBTM = ((BitmapDrawable) view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(baseBTM);
        detector.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) {
                        if (fakeFace != null){
                            setFakeFace(view, faces.get(0), baseBTM, fakeFace);
                            hideProgressDialog();
                        }else {
                            switch (face){
                                case FACE_1:
                                    face1BTM = createTrimmedBitmap(cutFaces(faces.get(0), baseBTM));
                                    mIvForDetect3.setImageBitmap(face1BTM);
                                    face1Done = true;
                                    checkFaces();
                                    break;
                                case FACE_2:
                                    face2BTM = createTrimmedBitmap(cutFaces(faces.get(0), baseBTM));
                                    mIvForDetect4.setImageBitmap(face2BTM);
                                    face2Done = true;
                                    checkFaces();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    public FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions buildCloudVisionOptions() {
        return new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
                .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.FAST)
                .build();
    }

    public static Bitmap createTrimmedBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        int imgHeight = bmp.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = bmp.getWidth();
        int smallX = 0, largeX = imgWidth, smallY = 0, largeY = imgHeight;
        int left = imgWidth, right = imgWidth, top = imgHeight, bottom = imgHeight;
        for (int i = 0; i < imgWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < imgHeight; j++) {
                if (bmp.getPixel(i, j) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    if ((i - smallX) < left) {
                        left = (i - smallX);
                    }
                    if ((largeX - i) < right) {
                        right = (largeX - i);
                    }
                    if ((j - smallY) < top) {
                        top = (j - smallY);
                    }
                    if ((largeY - j) < bottom) {
                        bottom = (largeY - j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, left, top, imgWidth - left - right, imgHeight - top - bottom);
        return bmp;
    }

    public Bitmap cutFaces(FirebaseVisionFace face, Bitmap baseBTM) {
        Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseBTM.getWidth(), baseBTM.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(baseBTM, 0, 0, null);
        int top = face.getBoundingBox().top;
        int left = Math.round(face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR).getPosition().getX());
        int right = Math.round(face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR).getPosition().getX());
        int bottom = face.getBoundingBox().bottom;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap.getWidth(), tempBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawOval(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, new Matrix(), paint);
        return output;
    }

    public void setFakeFace(ImageView view, FirebaseVisionFace face, Bitmap baseBTM, Bitmap fakeFace) {

        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseBTM.getWidth(), baseBTM.getHeight(), baseBTM.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        final Paint paintSRC = new Paint();
        final Paint paintDST = new Paint();

        int top = face.getBoundingBox().top;
        int left = Math.round(face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR).getPosition().getX());
        int right = Math.round(face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR).getPosition().getX());
        int bottom = face.getBoundingBox().bottom;
        int weight = right - left;
        int height = bottom - top;

        canvas.drawOval(left, top, right, bottom, paintSRC);
        paintSRC.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        paintDST.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR).getPosition().getX(), face.getBoundingBox().top);

        canvas.drawBitmap(baseBTM, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fakeFace, weight, height, false), left, top, paintDST);
        view.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } }
```